# How to post to facebook wall using facebook android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using this code to post a text to my facebook wall without opening a dialog window but it's not running !!

can anyone help me through it or suggest another solution/code ?

```
public void postToWall(String message) {
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", message);
    parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
    try {
        facebook.request("me");
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")) {
            showToast("Blank response.");
        }
        else {
            showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
        }

        finish();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please maybe explain what you mean by "it's not running"? Do you get an error message or something?

Comment: there was no errors, it just wasn't posting, anyways thanks for your concern the problem is fixed now, it wasn't in the posting code =)

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
public void postOnWall(String msg) {
            Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
             try {
                    String response = facebook.request("me");
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("message", msg);
                    parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
                    response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                            "POST");
                    Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
                    if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                            response.equals("false")) {
                       Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
                   }
             } catch(Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

Comment: @Aerrow how to initialize `facebook` object that you used for `facebook.request`?

Comment: @AJ.: FaceBook  facebook = new FaceBook(<YOUR APP ID>);